# WEKA FP-Growth java code

Tags: java, weka, data-mining

i'm trying to find a way to run weka fp-growth java code in ide but it needs the whole weka package(or this is what I thought, because it has errors when I copy it). is there any way for me to get the whole package with out downloading each file separately. 
this is the site i'm using to download it.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.12/weka/associations/FPGrowth.java?av=f

Comment: Maven takes care of this for you but it means learning how to use maven and setting dependencies to your weka package.  See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can download weka.zip file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-3-7/3.7.11/

Unzip it. And in your IDE, click on project and add external jars for the project, go to unzipped folder and select weka.jar

Now, you directly use weka in your java code by using `import weka.*;`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading from a random site from the internet, why don't you just go to the Weka *homepage* and download the entire source there?

Comment: it's not downloadable https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/tags/weka-dev-3.9.1/src/main/java/weka/associations/FPGrowth.java

Comment: Of course it is downloadable. Just *read*. And check the contents of the jar file, for a file called `weka-src.jar`